# How to include/require/load a file in ruby with instance variables

Tags: ruby, require, instance-variables

I would like to put a large variable definition in a separate file for the sake of getting it out of the way. I must be doing something wrong though, because my `puts` call isn't putting anything out.

my_class.rb:

```
class foobar
  def initialize
    require 'datafile.rb'
    puts @fat_data
  end
end
```

datafile.rb:

```
@fat_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Can you use require this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

my_class.rb:

```
class Foobar
  def initialize
    init_fat_data
    puts @fat_data
  end
end
```

datafile.rb:

```
class Foobar
  private

  def init_fat_data
    @fat_data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  end
end
```

Or, perhaps, change `class Foobar` in `datafile.rb` to `module MyData` and then include the module to `Foobar` class in `my_class.rb`.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know you could write class definitions over multiple declarations like that. Ruby is great!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the data out of the class definition, you could also use __END__ and DATA:

[Useless Ruby Tricks: DATA and __END__](http://shifteleven.com/articles/2009/02/09/useless-ruby-tricks-data-and-__end__)